# In R:how to extract part of list of list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list variable `rho` like following

```
$rs6139074
   V4  V5  V7
4 0.9 0.0 0.1
5 0.0 0.9 0.0
7 0.1 0.0 0.9

$rs6139072
   V4  V5  V7
4 0.9 0.0 0.1
5 0.0 0.8 0.0
7 0.1 0.0 0.9
```

How do I extract first 2 by 2 matrix of each list as following?

```
$rs6139074
       V4  V5
    4 0.9 0.0 
    5 0.0 0.9 

$rs6139072
       V4  V5  
    4 0.9 0.0 
    5 0.0 0.8
```

The aim to do this

```
lappy(rho[1:2,1:2],function(x) eigen(x)$values)
```

## data structure:

```
rho <- structure(list(rs6139074 = structure(c(0.9, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.9, 0, 
0.1, 0, 0.9), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("4", "5", 
"7"), c("V4", "V5", "V7"))), rs6139072 = structure(c(0.9, 0, 
0.1, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.1, 0, 0.9), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("4", "5", "7"), c("V4", "V5", "V7")))), .Names = c("rs6139074", 
"rs6139072"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to loop through the variable and `subset`:

```
lapply(rho, function(mat) mat[1:2, 1:2])
```

which gives:

```
$rs6139074
   V4  V5
4 0.9 0.0
5 0.0 0.9

$rs6139072
   V4  V5
4 0.9 0.0
5 0.0 0.8
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `lapply(rho, function(mat) eigen(mat[1:2, 1:2])$values)`

Comment: If you want to really squish it, you could `lapply(rho, \`[\`, 1:2, 1:2)`

Comment: `\`[\`` is just the standard extraction function that gets called for any subsetting, so `df[1:2,1:2]` is equivalent to `\`[\`(df,1:2,1:2)`

Comment: @thelatemail. I google it. But I cannot function any more information about ``[``. Can you send me a link?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE`

```
sapply(rho, function(mat) mat[1:2, 1:2], simplify = FALSE)
#$rs6139074
#   V4  V5
#4 0.9 0.0
#5 0.0 0.9

#$rs6139072
#   V4  V5
#4 0.9 0.0
#5 0.0 0.8
```