# in R:how to store number by order in list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a for loop like following

```
for(i in 1:2)
{
  eigeni=lapply(rho,function(mat) eigen(mat[1:i,1:i])$values)
  x=lapply(eigeni,function(x) i-sum(ifelse(x>1,x,1)-1))
}
```

When `i=1`,x is

```
> x
$rs6139074
[1] 0.241097

$rs1418258
[1] 0.241097
```

When `i=2`,x is

```
> x
$rs6139074
[1] 1.241097

$rs1418258
[1] 1.247
```

How can I store x by column for each iteration like following after this loop?
I would like something like following

```
for(i in 1:2)
    {
      eigeni=lapply(rho,function(mat) eigen(mat[1:i,1:i])$values)
      x[i]=lapply(eigeni,function(x) i-sum(ifelse(x>1,x,1)-1))
    }


 > x
 $rs6139074
 [1] 0.241097 1.241097

 $rs1418258
 [1] 0.241097 1.247
```

Following **Dave2e** answer
I got

```
> mylist
[[1]]
[[1]]$rs6139074
[1] 0.241097

[[1]]$rs1418258
[1] 0.241097


[[2]]
[[2]]$rs6139074
[1] 1.241097

[[2]]$rs1418258
[1] 1.247
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(x, data.frame))` possibly.

Comment: You can use something like `x <- lapply(1:2, function(i) { #... })` where `#...` is `eigeni=... ; lapply(eigeni, ...)`; notice I don't use `x=`, and the results can now use @Psidom's comment, I think.

Comment: This seems to be leading on from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385747/in-rhow-to-extract-part-of-list-of-list/38385778

Comment: If you don't mind using a package (and if I understand the question correctly), you can use `ldply` or `laply` from the `dplyr` package to apply a function over a list and return a data.frame or array, respectively.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, I cannot ask two question in 90 mins

Comment: replacing `x` with `mylist` for the comment I posted should get you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to define a empty list and append values onto it:

```
mylist<-list()

for(i in 1:2)
{
  eigeni=lapply(rho,function(mat) eigen(mat[1:i,1:i])$values)
  x=lapply(eigeni,function(x) i-sum(ifelse(x>1,x,1)-1))
  mylist[[i]]<-x
}
print(mylist)
```

Of course if you can use the lapply function, that would be the most condensed and most likely fastest method.